# Kubernetes Pod is not saving the data even though it has persistent storage

Tags: kubernetes, jbpm

I am using JBPM business-central which is deployed on K8s.
Below is my depolyment.apps where the persistent volume is attached .

```
kubectl edit deployment.apps/jbpm-server-full
     volumes:
      - name: jbpm-pv-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: jbpm-pv-claim
```

But when i restart the pod i am losing all the workspaces in business-central even though we have attached persistent volumes attached to the k8S pod.

Answer (score 1):

You need to mount that volume inside the container and write data into the mounted path

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: task-pv-pod
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: task-pv-storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: task-pv-claim
  containers:
    - name: task-pv-container
      image: nginx
      ports:
        - containerPort: 80
          name: "http-server"
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html"
          name: task-pv-storage
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-persistent-volume-storage/

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer i followed the link which you gave above and while attaching since my Pod is already running , i have edited the deployment.apps like below .         spec:
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /k8sdata/jbpmdata
          name: jbpm-pv-storage
      dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
      restartPolicy: Always
      schedulerName: default-scheduler
      securityContext: {}
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - name: jbpm-pv-storage
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: jbpm-pv-claim

Comment: Also little confused what needs to be given in - mountPath: "/usr/share/nginx/html" I gave my local disk path

Comment: it can be any path but the jbpn app need to write data in that path

Comment: since i have edited deployments it has created a new Pod and all my previous jbpm buniess central workspaces have lost.